# Where are the DB settings located?

Tags: database, acquia-dev-desktop

i've been learning Drupal 7 using Acquia DevDesktop and i have several sandbox type website running on my laptop but now i'm trying to access the databases from the command line. but in the settings.php almost the only that's not comment out are at the bottom, where it makes reference to inc.'s like this.

```
if (isset($_SERVER['DEVDESKTOP_DRUPAL_SETTINGS_DIR']) &&
file_exists($_SERVER['DEVDESKTOP_DRUPAL_SETTINGS_DIR'] .          '/loc_rmywebsite_local.inc')) 
  require($_SERVER['DEVDESKTOP_DRUPAL_SETTINGS_DIR'] .     '/loc_mywebsite_local.inc');
```

but then when i do a search for these inc files locally on my laptop, nothing comes up, as if they don't exist. so
One, where are these files?
and two, find where the DB settings are for these local sites so i can start learning how use the command line, or maybe Drush.

yes, i should probably have written down these setting but didn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find DB Settings of Acquia DevDesktop locally at following location

> C:\Users\YOUR_USER_NAME\.acquia\DevDesktop\DrupalSettings\loc_mywebsite_local.inc

In above path Replace YOUR_USER_NAME with apropriate user name that you login on system. This path for Windows 7.

Comment: thanks. but i cannot find. Mac seems to be quite different. i should be able to find if i just keep looking.

Comment: i just did a var dump and see the pathname is the same as what you printed. i guess i cannot find because the folder .acquia is a hidden file.

Comment: i found the files but curiously, the password is an empty string in the DB array settings. though everything else is set. also in the command if i write mysql -u username -p it says command not found.

Answer (score 4):

For Mac, open Terminal. By default it opens in your user home directory (/Users/"username").

The settings you are looking for are on a file in a hidden ".acquia" folder inside your user home directory.

On a freshly open Terminal window (meaning, from your user home directory, unless you changed its settings), just do the following to list the settings files for the Acquia Dev Desktop environments on your local computer:

```
ls .acquia/DevDesktop/DrupalSettings
```

Once you see the one you want, you can display its content using the cat command, for example if the file is named cld_devcloud_myveryownshinydrupal_dev_default.inc, then just type:

```
cat .acquia/DevDesktop/DrupalSettings/cld_devcloud_civila7_dev_default.inc
```

In any case, the full path you are looking for is:

```
/Users/your-own-mac-username/.acquia/DevDesktop/DrupalSettings/
```

Hope this helps. It took me a while to find it too and Acquia documentation makes no mention at all (or at least none that I could find).

Comment: Why the password field is empty?

Answer (score 2):

Couple of things.

For Windows, the DB settings are in the dir Rupesh listed. Very similar on a Mac as well:

/Users/YOUR_USER_NAME/.acquia/DevDesktop/DrupalSettings

There is a file in this directory for each site you have installed on Dev Desktop. Do not edit this file! However you can use this file to figure out where you database is, the name, etc.

While you can use drush to do a database backup, you can also use Dev Desktop to export a site archive which includes a sql file.

Comment: thanks, i'm trying to click the 'Answer is useful' but it won't let me

Comment: i'd found those earlier, after realizing one folder is hidden. but curious why those DB arrays have no password? weird

Comment: It's local dev so I assume they make the password optional.

Comment: @JonReid Why the password field is empty?